# How to burn DMGs on a Windows PC?

Tags: windows-7, dvd, burning, dmg-image

how can I burn `.dmg`s on Windows 7?

I would like to do it free :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly I know only [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) and [PowerISO](http://www.poweriso.com/) what would do the job. Try MagicISO trial.

Comment: magiciso says that the file does not exist or that it cant open. PowerISO fails the task at 50%.

Comment: it's a 7.5GB DMG, so it's DVD+R DL. (Verbatim)

Comment: Hmm try extracting it first and then pack it into an ISO. Or simply convert them, do not write them directly.

Comment: @TutorialPoint: If it fails the task at 50%, it's probably having trouble switching layers -- i.e. a DVD problem. You might want to get the brand called Verbatim; I've seen other brands that sometimes don't work in some drives but that work in others.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Anyiso, transmac, macdrive and they ALL work well. Power iso works as well.

Answer (score 0):

While it isn't explicitly listed as a supported filetype, you could try [imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/) — it supports many different file types, and could potentially do a DMG.

Comment: "unvalid or unsupported image file format!"

Comment: Darn. I'm sorry.