# How do I burn a .dmg DVD on my Windows PC, so that I can run it on my Mac?

Tags: windows, mac, installation, dvd, dmg-image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to burn DMGs on a Windows PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/150679/how-to-burn-dmgs-on-a-windows-pc)

I downloaded a 4.6GB .dmg file on my Windows computer.

What *Windows* program can burn this .dmg file to a DVD, so that I can run/install the DVD on my Mac?

Comment: duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/150679/how-to-burn-dmgs-on-a-windows-pc and http://superuser.com/questions/4105/how-to-convert-or-burn-a-dmg-image-file-on-windows

Comment: Are you sure you need to burn a DVD? Can you bring the file to the Mac and mount a disc image instead?